# Accessing CartoDB/SQL Console?

Tags: sql, carto

Lacking much programming experience, I've spent a lot of time familiarizing myself with HTML, CSS, and SQL over the past couple of days so that I could make a layer selector for a CartoDB visualization.

I eventually made a layer selector, but my SQL queries weren't working for some reason. Apparently I had to make the data table non-private. I was informed that I could have looked at the console and it would have told me the error.

Can someone tell how I can access this console?

I have no idea what that is. I was thinking it could be accessed via Linux terminal, but my platform right now is Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is information about the console they are probably talking about.

[Google Chrome Console.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

[And for Firefox.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)

[And for Safari.](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)

[And for IE.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)

They all provide similar abilities to give you information about your Javascript issues.